# How to store copied text into a variable in Python using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on some web scraping projects, where I scrape the data and store it into the CSV file. I am stuck in a case where I need to store copied the data into a variable.

Actually, the text is generated after clicking on a button and automatically copied, just I need to save this copied text into a variable. Now for this, I use following commands but nothing is working.

Command1-

```
   spam=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-control-name="copy_address]').click()
   print("copied text",spam)
```

it shows "copied text none"

Even I used pyperclip library as well but nothing works for me.

Command2-

```
   pyperclip.copy(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-control-name="copy_address"]').click())
   spam = pyperclip.paste()
```

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You are clicking the element in that `xpath` not copying its text, that is why your variable returns `None`.

Try:

```
spam=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-control-name="copy_address]').text
print(spam)
```

If it won't work, maybe the element you are getting is not a text. Try getting its html code instead using the `get_attribute` method:

```
spam=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-control-name="copy_address]')
your_text = spam.get_attribute('outerHTML')
print(your_text)
```

This will give you full html of the element you're interested in, then you just have to substring the result to get the text you need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Basically the text will come after the click event, in outerHTML, there is no text, to get the text we need to click on button then only text comes. I think some ajax technique is used for this.

Comment: Then the xpath you copied might not be the correct xpath. Click that button first, then whatever page that loads (excluding pop ups) you have to get the xpath of the text you want then do the method above.